# why we need to implement UiNavigationcontroller delegate in ImagePickerController in iphone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

hello all I am using Uiimagepickercontroller to record a video there I need to implement two delegates.. 1 is UINavigationcontroller delegate and 2 is UIImagepickercontroller delegate.If we not use navigationcontroller delegate its giving me warning at the code `picker.delegte=self`;

what is the necessity of UINavigationControllerDelegate..
My requirement is  I am recording a vedio automatically.. so after it stops recording It should go to the Screen saying that useThis ,Discard options and it plays the video what is captured?

Is there any way.. to do that ..
could any one tell me the way for this and what is the UINavigtaioncontrollerdelegate exactly?

Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

UIImagePickerController is a subclass of UINavigationController. It requires its delegate to implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol while still implementing the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol for its superclass.

That means you need to declare your delegate class like this:

```
@interface MyDelegate : NSObject <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                  UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

And then implement the required methods for both protocols.

Comment: Thankyou for your response.. But how i use this navigation controller delegate to see the preview of video that is captured...Thank you

Comment: It will automatically allows you to preview the video, right? What is your problem?

Comment: no ,, its not showing like that .. I hidden the cameracontrols and recording so in didfinishmethod I dismiss the viewcontroller so its just coming back the screen it gets called from.. Its not showing the Preview..

Comment: any help to get preview in this case

Comment: "implement the required methods for both protocols".... They're both only have optional methods... :P